# hacer caso omiso si confirm es cancelado

Tags: javascript

quiero que cuando se apreta en cancelar no se redirija a la url del link, como hacerlo?

```js
$('#concederRol').click(function() {
                      confirm("esta seguro de realizar esta accion? esta accion es irrevocable"); 
                   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="www.google.com" id="concederRol"> enviar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) retornará un valor `booleando` dependiendo de la opción que se seleccionó. , para este caso si se selecciona `cancelar` entonces retornará `false` , en el `if` verificamos esto con `!x` , si es así retornamos `false` para que no se ejecute la re dirección.

```js
$('#concederRol').click(function() {
    var x = confirm("esta seguro de realizar esta accion? esta accion es irrevocable"); 
    if(!x)return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="www.google.com" id="concederRol"> enviar
```

Comment: deberia usar window location?

Comment: eso soluciona mi problema

Comment: estaba esperando los 10 min para marcarla como correcta. solo eso